# How to make image fit in circular avatar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using a circle avatar on the sign-up page to let users can upload their profile images. However, the size of the image doesn't fit in the circle avatar. The image is too big for the circle avatar and I want to make it fit. How can I fix this problem? Thank you

The original profile image
[image]

How it looks in circle avatar
[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:io';

class SignupProfileImage extends StatefulWidget {
  SignupProfileImage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SignupProfileImage> createState() => _SignupProfileImageState();
}

class _SignupProfileImageState extends State<SignupProfileImage> {
  bool isUploadImage = false;
  var selectedImage;

  uploadProfileImage () async{
    var picker = ImagePicker();
    var image = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if(image != null) {
      setState(() {
        selectedImage = image.path;
      });
    }
    if (!mounted) return;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
        top: 140,
        right: 0,
        left: 0,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          child: Stack(
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            fit: StackFit.expand,
            children: [
              CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: isUploadImage && selectedImage != null ? FileImage(File(selectedImage)) : AssetImage('assets/face.jpg') as ImageProvider,
              ),
              Positioned(
                  bottom: -5,
                  left: 0,
                  right: -50,
                  child: RawMaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      uploadProfileImage();
                      setState(() {
                        isUploadImage = true;
                      });
                    },
                    elevation: 2.0,
                    fillColor: const Color(0xFFF5F6F9),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    shape: const CircleBorder(),
                    child: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt_outlined, color: Colors.blue,),
                  )
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72561039/13997210) answer hope its help to you just remove 2nd _white color `Container` in this code_

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ClipRRect** widget, wrap you **Image** widget with **ClipRRect** and pass **borderRadius**, you will get what you want. and you can fit **Image** by passing **BoxFit.fitheight** to Image widget:

Example:

```
ClipRRect(
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
       child: Image.asset(
                 'assets/images/tutorial_1_bg.png',
                  height: 200.0,
                  width: 200.0,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              )
```

Comment: Hi! I just did what you said and it worked! However, the width of the image is too long. It is same as the whole width of the phone screen. How can I fix that problem?

Comment: can you share the code snippet ?

Comment: Oh I did it with different way, but I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use ClipPath , and image fit property  BoxFit.fill

```
ClipPath(
      clipper: ShapeBorderClipper(shape:  const CircleBorder()),
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      child: Image.asset(
             'assets/images/tutorial_1_bg.png',
              height: 200.0,
              width: 200.0,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ))
```